# UIImageView animation inside UICollectionViewCell doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `Collection View` with 5 cells (pages).

First page user always see when opening the `Collection View` - is Welcome Page, which has `UIImageView` and 2 label beneath.

After the `Collection View` Controller `did load` I want to add a short animation to `UIImageView` to increase its size by 2 from original.

Here is how I tried to do that:

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? WelcomeOnboardingCollectionViewCell else { return }
        cell.animate()
    }
}
```

Here is the animation method:

```
class WelcomeOnboardingCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var subtitleLabel: UILabel!

func animate() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 3, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut) {
        self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 2, y: 2)
    }
}
}
```

But animation doesn't happen, I see only the initial small `UIImageView`, despite `print(cell)` is working, so the method is called.

I also tried to call `cell.animate()` in `cellForItemAt`, but then I see already increased `UIImageView` without animation and doesn't matter which animation duration was set in `animate()` method.

Also tried to call the next code in `scrollViewDidScroll` without any luck :

```
collectionView.visibleCells.forEach { ($0 as? WelcomeOnboardingCollectionViewCell)?.animate() }
```

Also tried to call on the cell `layoutIfNeeded()`, but it doesn't changed anything.

What do I miss?

The desired result: [CLICK](https://cln.sh/fLj1Oh)

**Working code after Duncan's suggestion:**

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if indexPath.item == 0 {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "WelcomeOnboardingCell", for: indexPath) as! WelcomeOnboardingCollectionViewCell
        
        cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "\(slides[indexPath.row].imageName)")
        cell.titleLabel.text = slides[indexPath.row].title
        cell.subtitleLabel.text = slides[indexPath.row].subtitle
        cell.animationPending = true
        return cell
   }
```

and CollectionViewCell class:

```
class WelcomeOnboardingCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var subtitleLabel: UILabel!

var animationPending = false

override func didMoveToSuperview() {
    if animationPending {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.animate()
        }
    }
    animationPending = false
}

private func animate() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0.4, options: .curveEaseInOut) {
        self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 2.3, y: 2.3)
        self.imageView.alpha = 1.0
    }
}
}
```

**Alternative:**

Call the `animate()` in ViewController's `viewDidAppear()`:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    collectionView.visibleCells.forEach { ($0 as? WelcomeOnboardingCollectionViewCell)?.animate() }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the `collectionView(_:willDisplay:forItemAt:)` method and the `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)` method are called before your cell is added to the view hierarchy. You can't trigger animation of a view until it is part of the view hierarchy.

I suggest adding the animation "smarts" to your `UICollectionViewCell` subclass (or to a content view that you put inside the collection view cell.

Have your `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)` set an "animationPending" property on your cell to true.

Then have your `UICollectionViewCell` respond to a `didMoveToSuperview()` call by checking it's  "animationPending" flag. If it's true, run your animation code and set the flag back to false.

Comment: Hi Duncan! Thank you for the reply! I tried to implement your suggestion, but when cell loads I see only the result without animation... I added the code to my initial post, please take a look. Also I found out that if I run animate() in VC `viewDidAppear()` everything works with animation. Maybe I didn't implement your solution correct?

Comment: Got it. Should perform the `animate()` inside `didMoveToSuperview()` on main thread. So wrap it in `DispatchQueue` fix an issue with animation. But could you please explain, what is the advantage of your solution rather than just to call the method in VC `viewDidAppear()`?

Comment: `viewDidAppear()` is a view controller method. When the `viewDidAppear()` method on your view controller that owns the collection view is called, your collection view cells won't yet be loaded. Or do you have a view controller for each cell?

Comment: No, I have only one Onboarding ViewController with one collectionViewCell. I paste the code I use in `viewDidAppear()` in my initial post, please take a look. When I use `collectionView.visibleCells.forEach{}` the animation works, so cells are loaded. But as I understood from your answer - it's not a constant, it can happen they won't be loaded.